# NoMethodError Unable to Solve

Tags: ruby, jboss, chef-infra

Unable to solve this error when it state NoMethodError

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jbosseap/recipes/default.rb

NoMethodError
-------------
No resource or method named jboss for `Chef::Recipe "default_deploy_list"'

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jbosseap/recipes/default_deploy_list.rb:1:in from_file
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jbosseap/recipes/default.rb:15:in from_file

> Relevant File Content:
>/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jbosseap/recipes/default_deploy_list.rb:

>  1 jboss 'testweb' do

 > 2:    source "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/chef.repos/testweb.zip"

  >3:    action :deploy

  >4:  end
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What is `jboss` in that recipe? You are likely missing a dependency in your `metadata.rb` file. Chef doesn't know anything about a `jboss['testweb']` resource that you're declaring.

Comment: To make this clearer, `jboss` is the type of recipe like `template` or `package` and that error is a somewhat roundabout way for Chef to say that no such resource type exists.